# Spring framework using validator after upgrade

Tags: spring, spring-validator

I am upgrading the spring framework from very old version to 5.3.9. In the current Spring configuration, I have below validation framework included. In the new spring,  I will not have the below info in the configuration file. How can I replace with validation in the new Spring framework ?

```
<bean id="editAdmin" class="abc.controller.EditAdminController">
      <property name="sessionForm"><value>true</value></property>
      <property name="synchronizeOnSession"><value>true</value></property>
      <property name="commandName"><value>AdminClass</value></property>
      <property name="commandClass"><value>abc.bean.AdminClass</value></property>
      <property name="formView"><value>Admin</value></property>
      <property name="successView"><value>view_admin.html</value></property>
      **<property name="validator"><ref bean="adminValidator"/></property>**
      <property name="dao"><ref bean="adminDAO"/></property>
    </bean>
```

How do I invoke validation in the controller using new spring version ?

I found below sample online. I think it will work but haven't tried yet.

> @RequestMapping(value = "/saveBasicInfoStep1", method =
> RequestMethod.POST) public String saveBasicInfoStep1(
> @Validated(BasicInfo.class)    @ModelAttribute("useraccount")
> UserAccount useraccount,    BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
> if (result.hasErrors()) {
> return "error";
> }
> return "success"; }

Thanks!

Comment: I would revert to Spring 5.3 and migrate first to annotation based controllers, then do the upgrade. This is code belonging to the `SimpleFormController` was has long been deprecated/superseded with annotation based controllers. So first migrate then upgrade.

Comment: @Denum - My question is specifically about using validations in latest framework.

Comment: Use `@Valid` on the `@MOdelAttribute` and you can setup the databinder (in an `@InitBinder` annotated method) with the existing validator. If that was your question it was poorly worded. Or you can try to rewrite your validation with annotations on the object.